# Calculating correlation and running a 2SLS regression on variables with different number of observations

Tags: r, regression, na

To run a 2SLS regression, I first need to get the correlation between two variables, educ and fatheduc.

One of them (the instrument, fatheduc) has some NA values, that I got rid of using:

```
fatheduc=na.omit(fatheduc)
```

But now my two variables do not have the same dimension, meaning that finding the correlation and running the first stage regression is impossible. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The rows from educ and fathereduc are observations from the same individual, so you can't (not just because the code won't run) remove observations from fathereduc and not from educ, you need to remove individuals, i.e. remove rows from both variables.

```
educ = educ[-which(is.na(fathereduc))] #you need to run this before removing the NA's from fathereduc
fatheduc = na.omit(fatheduc)
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I tried using:
```
cor(educ,fatheduc, use="complete.obs")
```
Would that also work or would I get a different result ?